# How to use wget after installing it ?

Tags: bash, wget, bash-on-windows

I do want to download documentation for me to view it offline but after installing it to this directory :

C:\wget\GnuWin32

when i try to open command prompt and go into that directory  and type wget into it.

it says

bash: wget: command not found

Comment: wget.exe perhaps?

Comment: is it in your path?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment you can either add the directory to the path (temporarily via 'set PATH=%PATH%;C:\wget\GnuWin32') or enter the command with leading '.\wget.exe' if you are in that directory.